# Tomato Firmware & TC-ATM Patch

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, tomato, wrt54gl

I have a router with the tomato speedmod patches applied (Viktek mod) and this is connected to an ADSL modem.

How do I use the tc-atm patch?

http://touristinparadise.blogspot.com/2008/04/linksys-wrt54gl-routers-improving.html

The website states:

> An example line in the tc command for my outbound interface is:
>
> tc class change dev vlan1 classid 1:10 htb prio 1 rate 800kbit ceil 800kbit overhead -4 atm
>
> And for inbound IMQ:
>
> tc class add dev imq0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb prio 1 rate 10000kbit ceil 10000kbit overhead 10 atm

Where would I put those options?  will this override the rates set in QoS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the web interface, go to `admin->scripts->firewall`